# Want to add if conditions in query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am creating one query to get the data per quarter.

I have *4 fields* in `user_target` table `quarter1`, `quarter2`, `quarter3` and `quarter4`
In each quarter there are 3 months ,

```
quater1 - Jan Feb March
quater2 - Apr May June
quater3 - July Aug Sept
quater4 - Oct Nov Dec
```

Now when I pass $P{month} as Jan,Feb or March then I should get the data for quarter1. Similarly when I pass $P{month} as Apr,May or June then I should get the data for quarter2 etc. I don't want to write 4 different queries for different months.
Can it be possible in a single query itself?

MY Query for quater1 is below:

```
select    sum(t.quarter1) as quarter ,
          s.name as sname, f.name as fname, m.name as pname 
from user_target t, res_salesteam s, 
     account_fiscalyear f,res_users u, res_users ru, account_month m
where t.salesteam_id = s.id and 
      t.fiscal_year = f.id and  
      f.id = $P{fiscalyear} and 
      p.fiscalyear_id = f.id and 
      m.id = $P{month} and 
      u.parent_id = ru.id and 
      ru.id = $P{name} and (u.tri_salesteam = s.id or ru.tri_salesteam = u.id)
group by s.name, f.name, m.name order by s.name
```

Comment: will you pass fulll date or just month ?

Comment: @KingFisher I am passing just id of month

Comment: it wil be easy if you can pass full date instead of month.

Comment: actually when I pass the month the month is having start_date and end_date fields. If I pass month as Jan its start_date is '2011-01-01' and end_date is '2011-01-31'

Comment: nop  we can use any date actully it works on full date .let me give answer

Comment: ok instead of Month I add date as '2011-01-10'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CASE ... END](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) logical construct

```
SELECT sum(CASE
    WHEN $P{month} IN ('Jan','Feb','March') THEN t.quarter1
    WHEN $P{month} IN ('Apr','May','June') THEN t.quarter2
    WHEN $P{month} IN ('July','Aug','Sept') THEN t.quarter3
    WHEN $P{month} IN ('Oct','Nov','Dec') THEN t.quarter4
    ELSE 0 END) AS quarter,
    s.name as sname, f.name as fname, m.name as pname
  FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

use MYSQL function `QUARTER()` to get quarter of passed date and get `sum`  according to returned quarter using `if /else`

Try  below :

```
select sum(if(QUARTER(start_date)=1,t.quarter1,0)) as quarter1,
SUM(if(QUARTER(start_date)=2,t.quarter2,0)) as quarter2,
SUM((QUARTER(start_date)=3,t.quarter3,0)) as quarter3,
SUM(IF(QUARTER(start_date)=4,quarter4,0)) as quarter4,s.name as sname, f.name as fname, m.name as pname 
    from user_target t, res_salesteam s, account_fiscalyear f,res_users u, res_users ru, account_month m
    where t.salesteam_id = s.id and t.fiscal_year = f.id and  f.id = $P{fiscalyear} and p.fiscalyear_id = f.id and m.id = $P{month}
    and u.parent_id = ru.id and ru.id = $P{name} and (u.tri_salesteam = s.id or ru.tri_salesteam = u.id)
    group by s.name, f.name, m.name order by s.name
```

Comment: Can we use sum(if(Quarter(m.name) in ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'),t.quarter1,0)) as quarter1 here instead sum(if(QUARTER(start_date)=1,t.quarter1,0)) as quarter1

Comment: No.  input to quarter function is date